# Best way to position image in the same spot on all devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, dpi

I have realized that I am not 100% sure what is the best way to position some UI element so that it appears on the same spot on all devices.

So far these are the options:

1. Set `dp` padding for each device
2. Make `View` above this image and change it's padding for each device
3. Calculate screen size in `Java code` and from the code set its locate in generics way. For example, set that image is located 1/5 screen height from top and apply this formula depending on current device's screen height.
4. Similar to point 2., but instead of using fixed `dp`, I play around with `layout_weight` of elements in question

What seems to be the best way?

Is there a better way which I did not mention here?

Thanks

Comment: use layout_weight to set ui at same spots in all resolutions.

Comment: "Same spot" as relative to what? Screen top, screen bottom? There are dozens of screen sizes, so you must be more specific in what you mean. DIP and layout weights were created to solve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two best options are as follows:

1. In code - calculate screen size and work with percentage of the screen.
2. Use `layout_weight` for your views and `weight_sum` for the parent view.

A small example for the code approach - Lets say you want a View to be exactly 25 percent of screen width:

```
 WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) _context.getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
 int screenWidth = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
 YOUR_VIEW.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (screenWidth * 0.25);
```

Comment: In code?? Really? I put this as option but I never thought that this is a realistic option. Do you use this approach?

Comment: Yeah. I'll prefer the weight approach first, but sometimes you  no choice.

Comment: So how do YOU do with weight approach. Do you divide the screen in regions (in head or on paper) and then calculate the right weight or there is a better approach?

Comment: Regarding the weight approach: Yeah - the idea is to divide the screen into N sections. Then set weight_sum="N" for the parent view and set layout_weight="N/WHATEVER_YOU_WANT"

Comment: Do you indeed work in code like in the example and not in XML? Or you made this only for myself as an example?

Comment: As I said, I'd prefer not to do it the code way, but I encountered situations where I had no choice (usually caused by designers' crazy ideas :)).  The example above is just something I wrote for you.. :)